# Synchronizing in-game clock vs real world clocks across servers started at different times

Tags: lua, synchronization, roblox, time

Regardless if you know how Roblox works or if you know Lua syntax, I just need an algorithm/equation here.

Currently, at the start of each server, I reference the seconds of a centralized clock since 00:00:00 June 1, 1970 (UTC). I want to synchronize all servers in-game times by referencing the same clock and then run at a fraction of real world's time in each server separately. So I have a ratio of a real-world second to my in-game second.

Where I'm stuck at though is when I start a server, then a second one at 100 seconds later, I'm referencing real-world time at the start of both, but the first one has already ran 100 in-game seconds so it's now out of sync.

I'm trying not to have to make a shared value from which to pull the only clock onto every server. So is there any possible way to use like a catch-up function? So I catch up from the time missed out between those real world 100 seconds that is now like 1 hour differential between servers?

Any algorithms or equations for that?

Comment: Why not take the seconds since epoch and divide them by a factor to get your current ingame time?

Answer (score 0):

Try `os.date`:

```
local date = os.date("!*t")
local minute = (date.hour + [A number for timezones]) * 60 + date.min
```

Comment: This question could be improved by additionally commenting on how this code is solving OP's issue.